# Possible negation of iostream by stdafx.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When i attempted to build it using Visuale studios (2017 community)
I got an error telling me to include "stdafx.h" (code C1010)
When i do this i get several issues telling me that strings i have
defined are not defined and other issues that usaually only happen to me if I 
 forget iostream. This is the only compiler that I have used, however online compilers seem to work (https://onlinegdb.com,  http://cpp.sh)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
string var1;
std::string pass;
std::cout << "Enter Any word" << std::endl;
std::cin >> pass;
cout << "1.what is 9 x 9" << endl;
std::cin >> var1;
cout << "2.what is 9 x 8" << endl;
std::cin >> var1;
cout << "3.what is 19 x 2" << endl;
std::cin >> var1;
cout << "4.what is 27 x 10" << endl;
std::cin >> var1;
cout << "5.what is 87 x 90" << endl;
std::cin >> var1;
cout << "6.what is 989 + 10" << endl;
std::cin >> var1;
cout << "7.What languages can Putin speak" << endl;
std::cin >> var1;
cout << "8.what is the square of 100" << endl;
std::cin >> var1;
cout << "9.What is the first word in the family guy theme song" << endl;
std::cin >> var1;
cout << "What is the answer to #5" << endl;
std::cin >> var1;
cout << "What is the answer to #7" << endl;
std::cin >> var1;
cout << "What is the answer to #9" << endl;
std::cin >> var1;
cout << "what is 989 + 10" << endl;
std::cin >> var1;
cout << "what was your word?" << endl;
cin >> var1;
if (var1 == pass)
{
    cout << "correct";
}
else
{
    cout << "wrong, you stynk";
}
}
```

Comment: You need to disable precompiled headers in your project settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [disable use of precompiled headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0atkd6c.aspx) by going to **Project properties -> C/C++ -> Precompiled headers** and select either **Not use** or **Create**.

Alternatively, include `"stdafx.h"` and move other includes to that file.